# Total number of records and their reason SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to write a query that get total number of records (booking) using the `COUNT(*)` function. I have a column `Type` in the database and in the next column I want to show type of record e.g output of query be like

- Total Booking -> 10
- Booking Type -> 3 wedding ceremony, 4 Birthday Party, 3 family Event (this will be in single cell next to total Booking)

Someone please help me.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, it will give you the total count of each type, with an overall total at the top.

```
SELECT     'Total Bookings', COUNT(*)
FROM       BookingTable

UNION

SELECT     [Type], COUNT(*)
FROM       BookingTable
GROUP BY   [Type]
```